# How can I provide custom error messages using JAXP DocumentBuilder?

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

I want to provide my own message from the validation done in `DocumentBuilder`, rather than the one from `XMLMessages.properties`.

Now I see that a property [`error-reporter`](http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/error-reporter) needs to be set to a class which extends `XMLErrorReporter`.

However, I've not been able to get `ComponentManager` from `Document`/`Builder`/`Factory`.

Doing parsing of string in `SAXParseException` is the last option, but I'm just thinking there may be a 'best practice' way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

have you already looked at [DocumentBuilder#setErrorHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setErrorHandler(org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler))?

if yes, could you explain why this approach doesn't work for you?

Comment: ErrorHandler kicks in with already formed string. ( e.g. The element of type Foo should be (bar)* ). The proper message should be ' The element 'Foo' should contain subelements 'bar' only'.

I can get the exhaustive list from XMLMessages.properties, and map them to the string that i want to print